# How to transform coloudwatch log events to insert records in ElasticSearch via Kinesis Data Firehose

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to stream my cloudwatch logs to AWS Opensearch(ElasticSearch) by creating a kinesis firehose subscription filter.
I want to understand does Kinesis data firehose supports bulk insert to the Elastic Search via bulk API or it inserts single records ?

So basically, I have created a lambda transformer which aggregates the Cloudwatch Log messages and transforms it to the format required for the bulk insert API of elastic search, I have tested my data format by directly calling the bulk API of elasticsearch and it works fine, however when I try to do the same via firehose I get following error :

```
message : One or more records are malformed. Please ensure that each record is single valid JSON object and that it does not contain newlines
error code : OS.MalformedData
```

The transformed data :

```
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"/aws/lambda/HelloWorldLogProducer","_id":"36495659535505340260631192776509739326813505134549729280"}}
{"timeMillis":1636521972493,"thread":"main","level":"INFO","loggerName":"helloworld.App","message":"Inflating logs to increase size","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger","contextMap":{"AWSRequestId":"332de390-42b3-44dd-937a-cc4089ff9510"},"threadId":1,"threadPriority":5,"jobId":"${ctx:request_id}","clientUUID":"${ctx:client_uuid}","clientUUIDHeader":"${ctx:client_uuid_header}"}
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"/aws/lambda/HelloWorldLogProducer","_id":"36495659535884452929006213369915846537448527280151396358"}}
{"timeMillis":1636521973189,"thread":"main","level":"INFO","loggerName":"helloworld.App","message":"{ \"message\": \"hello world\", \"location\": \"3.137.161.28\" }","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger","contextMap":{"AWSRequestId":"332de390-42b3-44dd-937a-cc4089ff9510"},"threadId":1,"threadPriority":5,"jobId":"${ctx:request_id}","clientUUID":"${ctx:client_uuid}","clientUUIDHeader":"${ctx:client_uuid_header}"}
```

It seems that firehose does not supports bulk insert, like the cloud watch to opensearch subscription filter does, however I cannot define the index name in opensearch subscription filter.

Does anyone faced a similar problem before ?

Answer (score 0):

After getting transformed data from the lambda transformer, Kinesis Firehose adds the index details on top of it. So if you want to use it for opensearch bulk api you have to remove the index data from the first object as it will be added by the firehose.

In your case data returned from the lambda transformer is

```
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"/aws/lambda/HelloWorldLogProducer","_id":"36495659535505340260631192776509739326813505134549729280"}}
{"timeMillis":1636521972493,"thread":"main","level":"INFO","loggerName":"helloworld.App","message":"Inflating logs to increase size","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger","contextMap":{"AWSRequestId":"332de390-42b3-44dd-937a-cc4089ff9510"},"threadId":1,"threadPriority":5,"jobId":"${ctx:request_id}","clientUUID":"${ctx:client_uuid}","clientUUIDHeader":"${ctx:client_uuid_header}"}
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"/aws/lambda/HelloWorldLogProducer","_id":"36495659535884452929006213369915846537448527280151396358"}}
{"timeMillis":1636521973189,"thread":"main","level":"INFO","loggerName":"helloworld.App","message":"{ \"message\": \"hello world\", \"location\": \"3.137.161.28\" }","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger","contextMap":{"AWSRequestId":"332de390-42b3-44dd-937a-cc4089ff9510"},"threadId":1,"threadPriority":5,"jobId":"${ctx:request_id}","clientUUID":"${ctx:client_uuid}","clientUUIDHeader":"${ctx:client_uuid_header}"}
```

After reaching to the firehose it get transformed as

```
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"/aws/lambda/HelloWorldLogProducer","_id":"36495659535505340260631192776509739326813505134549729280"}}
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"/aws/lambda/HelloWorldLogProducer","_id":"36495659535505340260631192776509739326813505134549729280"}}
{"timeMillis":1636521972493,"thread":"main","level":"INFO","loggerName":"helloworld.App","message":"Inflating logs to increase size","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger","contextMap":{"AWSRequestId":"332de390-42b3-44dd-937a-cc4089ff9510"},"threadId":1,"threadPriority":5,"jobId":"${ctx:request_id}","clientUUID":"${ctx:client_uuid}","clientUUIDHeader":"${ctx:client_uuid_header}"}
{"index":{"_index":"test","_type":"/aws/lambda/HelloWorldLogProducer","_id":"36495659535884452929006213369915846537448527280151396358"}}
{"timeMillis":1636521973189,"thread":"main","level":"INFO","loggerName":"helloworld.App","message":"{ \"message\": \"hello world\", \"location\": \"3.137.161.28\" }","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger","contextMap":{"AWSRequestId":"332de390-42b3-44dd-937a-cc4089ff9510"},"threadId":1,"threadPriority":5,"jobId":"${ctx:request_id}","clientUUID":"${ctx:client_uuid}","clientUUIDHeader":"${ctx:client_uuid_header}"}
```

which breaks the syntax of the bulk api so try removing the index of the first object and it should work fine after that.